# How to make edges more accurate?

Tags: c#, emgucv, image-recognition, edge-detection

I make an app for comparison patterns of shoes footprints using C# + EmguCV. This is what I already have: [Photo1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGlq5.png). But there's one toruble. I need to make edges more smooth and accurate. How can I do this in my case?

```
output = (new Image<Gray, byte>(input)).ThresholdBinaryInv(new Gray(ThresholdSlider.Value), new Gray(255));
output = output.Canny(200, 200);
Input.Source = BitmapToImageSource(input);
Output.Source = BitmapToImageSource(output.Bitmap);
```

Comment: Could you please explain more details about "make edges more smooth and accurate"? Do you mean the images not display smooth and accurate in your application when you change or display the images? how do you display these images?

Comment: I mean exactly processing of image. It would be better to get rid of too small areas and smooth the lines. Maybe there are some EmguCV functions for it, or something like that?